# error in executing sess.run()

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, semantic-segmentation

I wanna execute my graph model but I am having difficulty. The code is:

```
epoch_x, epoch_y = features, labels
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {"x:0": epoch_x, "y:0": epoch_y})
```

and the error is:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>   1067             subfeed_t = self.graph.as_graph_element(subfeed,
>   allow_tensor=True,
>   -> 1068                                                     allow_operation=False)    1069           except Exception as e:
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in
>   as_graph_element(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)    2707
>   with self._lock:
>   -> 2708       return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)    2709
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py in
>   _as_graph_element_locked(self, obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)    2749                          "exist. The operation, %s, does not
>   exist in the "
>   -> 2750                          "graph." % (repr(name), repr(op_name)))    2751         try:
>
> KeyError: "The name 'x:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The
>   operation, 'x', does not exist in the graph."
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        22 #             feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y}
>        23 
>   ---> 24             sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {"x:0": epoch_x, "y:0": epoch_y})
>        25             train_loss.append(sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y}))
>        26             train_accuracy.append(sess.run(accr, feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y}))
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>       893     try:
>       894       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
>   --> 895                          run_metadata_ptr)
>       896       if run_metadata:
>       897         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)
>
> D:\AnacondaIDE\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py
>   in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
>   1069           except Exception as e:    1070             raise
>   TypeError('Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: '
>   -> 1071                             + e.args[0])    1072     1073           if isinstance(subfeed_val, ops.Tensor):
>
> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'x:0'
>   refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'x', does not
>   exist in the graph.

I have also tried the following statement:

```
sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {"x": epoch_x, "y": epoch_y})
```

Then the error is:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        22 #             feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y}
>        23 
>   ---> 24             sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})
>        25             train_loss.append(sess.run(cost, feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y}))
>        26             train_accuracy.append(sess.run(accr, feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y}))
>
> NameError: name 'x' is not defined

Note that `print(features.shape)` yields:

> (4000, 6000, 3)

I am using Tensorflow-gpu (1.3.0).

Comment: Have you tried removing the quotes, i.e. : `sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {x: epoch_x, y: epoch_y})` as per [the tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/io_ops/placeholders) ?

Comment: post the code where you define placeholders

Comment: @Ksyqo qoutes were a problem and Pietro's answer also helped as I hadn't declared placeholder before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the feed dict there should be no quotes, but the keys should be the python variables pointing to the placeholders you want to feed.

For instance, if when declaring your placeholder you have something like

```
pl_ = tf.placeholder(...., name='placeholder_1')
```

then you should RUN THIS

```
sess.run(...., feed_dict={pl_: value})
```

and NOT THIS

```
sess.run(..., feed_dict={'placeholder_1': value})
```